# jQuery: push a href to another anchor, multiple times and separately

Tags: jquery, wordpress, plugins, anchor

I'm using a plugin on Wordpress to load Facebook events into a web page. I then hide the anchor which the plugin puts over the whole area, and instead create a small anchor at the bottom of each event div.

So far so good, but if I have multiple events (all events have the same classes in this plugin) all small anchors point to the first `.fb-event-anchor`. I could do something like `.fb-event-anchor.eq(0)`, then `.eq(1)`etcetera but I'd much rather have a more waterproof solution that handles all anchors. Does anyone know how to correctly pair all original and new links?

jQuery:

```
var fblink = $('.fb-event-anchor').attr("href");
$('.fb-event-anchor').parent('.fb-event').append( '<a class="fb-event-anchor-new" target="_blank" href='+ fblink +'>Bekijk dit evenement op facebook</a>' );
```

html:

```
<div class='fb-event'>
   <a class="fb-event-anchor" href="http://www.facebook.com/event.php?eid=1165884803462190"  target="_blank">
        <div class="fb-event-desc"><img src=https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/t31.0-8/s720x720/13920278_1335410149821833_1686522516711277604_o.jpg />
            <div class='fb-event-title'>Spiritueel weekend - Een stapje verder</div>
            <div class='fb-event-time'>10 september 2016 &#183; 10:00 -<br>11 september 2016 &#183; 17:00</div>
            <div class='fb-event-location'>Balance in Life</div>
            <div class='fb-event-description'>Lots</div>
       </div>
   </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work - enumerate all the `$('.fb-event-anchor')` elements and go from there

```
$('.fb-event-anchor').each(function(){
   var $anchor = $(this);
   $anchor.parent('.fb-event')
                   .append( '<a class="fb-event-anchor-new" target="_blank" href='+ $anchor.attr("href") +'>Bekijk dit evenement op facebook</a>' );
});
```

Comment: Great, thanks. I knew it had to be _something_ with $(this) but you nailed it